# How do libraries work at compile & link times

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, libraries

Im new to c++, getting an understanding on how libraries work, i know what a library is, but i was hoping for a quick summary of how it works at both compile time and link time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

- At compile time you compile your program using the library's headers.
- At link time the linker basically looks up the symbols that the compiler found in the library's headers in the library's binaries so that your program knows what code in the library's binaries to execute when your program uses symbols from that library (at run time).